# How to check whether code will work on CF9 server while working on CF10 server?

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have installed CF10 server installed on my local machine. We are migrating from CF9 to CF10. We use CFWheels framework for development. There are certain projects which are still on CF9. I would like to know, is there any way to check whether my code will work on CF9 server as well while working on CF10 server.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way is to run the applications in development on the correct versions of ColdFusion.

I have projects that use different versions of ColdFusion and I simply have multiple versions installed on my development machine and start up whatever version I need based on which project I am working on. This ensures that the code I am writing will work with the version I need.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your answer. 
That will solve my problem. I wonder why i didn't thought of that myself. :)